# PHP sessions: use ini_set or put in php.ini?

Tags: php, session

I am working to create a custom PHP session class, and I am going through an online example.

In the constructor of the custom session class, there are many `ini_set()` calls for various `session.xxx` parameters (`hash_function`, `cookie_secure`, `cookie_httponly`, etc.)

Is there any reason to use `ini_set` rather than just putting these settings in the `php.ini` file itself?  I realize the `ini_set` only lasts for the duration of the script. But since I will always be using the same session config across my web app, and I have no need for the default config of PHP sessions, can I just save time/processing by putting all my settings in the `php.ini`?

I am using shared hosting (at least for now during development and testing), and I have one master php.ini file that will apply to all pages.  Also running PHP 5.4.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I'm sure the ini_set() calls are pretty efficient, there is no reason to use them if you can set things up in the php.ini.  Those settings primarily exist for situations where people truly are in "shared" setup (Apache + Mod_php for example) and have no ability to change the global server settings for php.

There are a few settings where overriding makes sense, but not in the case of most of the session settings.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I wanted to be sure and couldn't find the answer anywhere.  Much appreciated!